# $\sqrt{-7}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number different from 2 and 7. Let $\zeta\in\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ a primitive 7-th root of unity, and define
$$\alpha=\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4, \ \ \beta=\zeta^3+\zeta^5+\zeta^6$$

a) Prove that $\alpha+\beta=-1$. (this one is clear)

b) Prove that:

$\alpha^p=\alpha$ if $p$ is a square modulo 7, and

$\alpha^p=\beta$ if $p$ is not a square modulo 7.

This is the question I’m having trouble with. Also:

c) Let $\sqrt{-7}\in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ be a square root of -7. Prove that $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p\iff \sqrt{-7}\in\mathbb{F}_p$. Hint: $f=(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$. (Here I’ve arrived at $f=X^2+X+2$).

Any hints on this problem?

Comment: Hint for b): Frobenius. Can you list the quadratic residues and non-residues modulo $7$?

Comment: Hint for c): Quadratic formula.

Comment: (I think) the quadratic residues mod 7 are 1,2,4. Then the non-residues are 0,3,5,6?

Comment: Toss out zero (by convention, not needed in this exercise). Ok. What do you get when you apply Frobenius to $\alpha$?

Comment: I think I see it. If $p$ is a square mod 7, the only possibilities are: $p=1,2,4$. Then you check taking congruences mod 7 that if $p=1$, $\alpha^p=\alpha$, and similarly for $p=2,7$.

Comment: For c), once you know $X=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-7}}{2}$, the result is trivial, right?

Comment: @cut Remember that $p$ has to be a prime for $\mathbb{F}_p$ to be defined.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks. Already corrected.

Comment: Correct. Consider posting a compilation of those to an answer for more feedback